# MongoDB Dynamic Field Creation

Tags: python, json, mongodb

I have a dictionary to be inserted dynamically in MongoDB.

Current MongoDB document-

```
"Customers":{
    "Payment":{
        "CustomerDetails":{
           "Source":"Visa Card",
           "Name" :"John",
       }
    }
}
```

The document that I am trying to insert into this through python dictionary object -

```
    final=  {"CustomerPayable":["Month":"Feb-1FN-2018","Details":
["Code":"ghg23","AmtPayable": "123.00"]]}
```

The query I am trying -

```
 db.collection.update({"UserID":UserID},{ '$push':{    
    'Customers.Payment.Output':final}})
```

I wanted the dynamic field of "Output" to be created through the above query. Expected output-

```
 "Customers":{
        "Payment":{
            "CustomerDetails":{
               "Source":"Visa Card",
               "Name" :"John",
           },
          "Output":{"CustomerPayable":["Month":"Feb-1FN-2018",Details:
    ["Code":"ghg23","AmtPayable": "123.00"]]}
        }
    }
```

Any help is great.Thanks in advance

Comment: you'd better use a db model to handle it

Comment: $push for inserting data into arrays.Use $set instead. `db.collection.update({"UserID":UserID},{ '$set':{    
    'Customers.Payment.Output':final}})`

Answer (score 0):

The following code should achieve your desired results.

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient()
db = client.stackoverflow
collection = db.stackoverflow

a = {"Customers":{ "Payment":{ "CustomerDetails":{ "Source":"Visa Card", "Name" :"John"}}}}
collection.insert(a)

# Prints object before update.
cur = collection.find_one({"Customers.Payment.CustomerDetails.Name":"John"})
print(cur)


final = {"CustomerPayable":{"Month":"Feb-1FN-2018","Details":
                           {"Code":"ghg23","AmtPayable": "123.00"}}}

collection.update({"Customers.Payment.CustomerDetails.Name":"John"},
                  {'$push':{'Customers.Payment.Output':final}})

# Prints object after update.
cur = collection.find_one({"Customers.Payment.CustomerDetails.Name":"John"})
print(cur)
```

A couple things wrong with your code are:

1. In you `final` declaration you tried to use dictionary syntax inside of a list.
2. In your update query you don't have a field called `UserID` for I changed it to query on `Name`

Anyways, I hope this helps.

Comment: Did this meet your needs?